# Excel VBA listbox selection filters

Tags: excel, vba

im self taught VBA user, trying to get the below code to be a bit more flexible, it works fine but i duplicate it for every row(new button/macro in every row),  the below code filters based on range in y37, however i would like the user to select from list (z37-z59) and then set the filterx to the corresponding value from (y37-59), ie user select from list populated  from z37-z59 ie Joe blogs from a list and this then sets filterx range  to y value jblogs01

PS i only posted the small bit of code for ease of use
I'm also making this up as i go along so feel free to give feedback on anyother bits.

```
 Set filterx = Range("y37")
    Sheets("DATA").Select
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$BL$300000").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:= _
        filterx
```

Comment: What type of button are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Forms buttons, then the macro which is called from the button can get the name of the button shape using `Application.Caller`.  You can then use that to get a reference to the button itself, and via its `TopLeftCell` property get to the row it's on.

Untested, but should get you on the way.  Link all your buttons to this sub.

```
Sub DoFilter()

    Dim filterx As Range

    Set filterx = Activesheet.Shapes(Application.Caller). _
                                     TopLeftCell.EntireRow.Cells(1,"Y")
    With Sheets("DATA")
        .Select
        .ShowAllData
        .Range("$A$1:$BL$300000").AutoFilter Field:=10, _
                                             Criteria1:= filterx
    End with

End Sub
```